# Add bitbucket repository to heroku project

Tags: node.js, git, heroku

I set-up a heroku Node project. Everything works fine but I would like to be able to push also on my bibucket repository. Git is set-up for Herokuy but when I try to add the bitbucket repository with the command:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:MYUSERNAME_/PROJECTNAME.git
```

I get the following error:

```
fatal: remote origin already exists.
```

So I tried to run the command

```
git push origin master
```

And I get the response:

```
Username for 'https://github.com':
```

How can I push both in heroku and on my bitbucket repository?

Comment: you mean, instead of hosting your code on heroku you want to host it bitbucket and use that in heroku?

Comment: In the other project I have I can run "git push heroku master" and push all the code on heroku and run as well "git push origin master" and push all the code in my bitbucket repository!

Comment: can you paste the output of `git remote -v`?

Answer (score 0):

You already have an origin repo defined (as github) so if you have the git project in bitbucket so you just need to reference as a new repo

```
git remote add bitbucket git@bitbucket.org:MYUSERNAME_/PROJECTNAME.git
```

then you will be able to run

```
git push bitbucket master (or any branch you have defined)
```

If you do not want to use github anymore and replace your `origin` repo with bitbucket, do

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org:MYUSERNAME_/PROJECTNAME.git
```

and then

```
git push origin master
```

will push to your bitbucket repo - make sure to follow heroku instructions to add the heroku repo and push your files there to be deployed

Answer (score 0):

Deendayal Garg gave me the right hint: with:

```
git remote -v
```

I could see that I had the original repository as origin remote. I deleted that, I unshallowed it (because the original repository was cloned with the -depth option) and I finally could add my personal bitbuket remote!